# Как их подружить REALM + Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, realm

Как реализовать это все в  Activity.

Realm модели

```
public class Events extends RealmObject {

private int id;
private String title;
private String description;
private String place;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}

public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}
```

Activity.class

```
public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Gson gson;
private OkHttpClient localclient;
private Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    localclient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new       LocalResponseInterceptor(this)).build();
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().client(localclient)
            .baseUrl("http//:localhost")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);
    }
}
```

Интерфейс для Retrofit

```
public interface HApi {
    @GET("/events")
    Call<RealmList<Events>> event (@FieldMap Map<String,String> map);
}
```

filejson.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Festival",
    "description": "Festival of classical music. All welcome",
    "place": "New York City"
  }
]
```

и класс для filejson.json, чтоб он забирал данные с него.

```
public class LocalResponseInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private Context context;

private String scenario = null;

public LocalResponseInterceptor(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
}

public void setScenario(String scenario) {
    this.scenario = scenario;
}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    URL requestedUrl = request.url().url();
    String requestedMethod = request.method();

    String prefix = "";
    if (this.scenario != null) {
        prefix = scenario + "_";
    }

    String fileName = (prefix + requestedMethod + requestedUrl.getPath()).replace("/", "_");
    fileName = fileName.toLowerCase();

    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "raw",
            context.getPackageName());

    if (resourceId == 0) {
        Log.wtf("YourTag", "Could not find res/raw/" + fileName + ".json");
        throw new IOException("Could not find res/raw/" + fileName + ".json");
    }

    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);

    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(inputStream);
    if (mimeType == null) {
        mimeType = "application/json";
    }

    Buffer input = new Buffer().readFrom(inputStream);

    return new Response.Builder()
            .request(request)
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
            .code(200)
            .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), input.size(), input))
            .build();
    }
  }
```